# Multilanguage Post Titles not Translating with List Category Posts Plugin

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

For the most part the plugin [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) works great.

I just have one problem with it: when I try to show the title and excerpt of a post it shows all translations at the same time, rather than just the translation relative to the selected languages.

I'm using [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/) for the languages. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: How are you showing the title and excerpt? Can you add the relevant code to your question? Or a link to a snapshot?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. for example on the following page: http://yoga-dinamico.hl53.dinaserver.com/en/talleres/ , using the plugin "list category post", i try to show a list of all the posts from a cateogry with this code: [catlist name=talleres thumbnail=yes thumbnail_size=52,52 excerpt=yes]. in the footer, in the Archive section is happening something similar.

Comment: Well, let's hope the plugin author see this post, because that's a handicap of LCP. Anyway, there are solutions on [WordPress forums](http://wordpress.org/search/list-category-posts+qtranslate?forums=1) on how to hack the plugin to make it work with qTranslate... Saludos!

Comment: thank you so much. i found a hint towards the solution exactly where you advised me. i think the solution was a bit outdated,but with a bit of digging, i made the following change: in file include/CartListDisplayer.php, in function get_post_title() i added the following code in first line before anything else: if (function_exists('qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage')) {
    $single->post_title = esc_html(qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage($single->post_title));
   }. needs to be done with all other fields that need translation.thank you so much

Comment: bilyana, glad to hear, but please answer your own question and in a couple of days mark it as the correct one. Haven't said, but benvingut a WPSE!

Comment: Please, read the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq), and you'll even earn your first bronze badge ;o)

Comment: i read it but the accepted button is not showing for me. it just show the mark as favorite.

Comment: You are confusing Questions with Answers, take a look down the page and you'll see a text box titled *Your Answer*, you to write it down, wait 2 days and mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hint towards the solution exactly where you advised me. I think the solution was a bit outdated, but with a bit of digging, I made the following change:
in file `include/CartListDisplayer.php`, in `function get_post_title()` I added the following code in first line before anything else:

```
if ( function_exists( 'qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage' ) ) 
{ 
    $single->post_title = esc_html(
        qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage( $single->post_tit‌​le )
    ); 
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me but copy-pasting directly did not, there was an encoding issue of some sort with the "$single->post_tit‌​le" part so I had to copy-paste that from further down in the CartListDisplayer.php file.